# PowerCLI: How can I find an ESXi host's system memory?

Tags: vmware-esxi, powercli

A view of a VM host gives me the field .Config.ConsoleReservation, but ESXi doesn't have the console any more. The vSphere GUI shows total memory and system memory for ESXi hosts.

How can I get an ESXI host's system (vmkernel) memory?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
$totalmemoryB = $view.Hardware.MemorySize
$totalmemoryMB = [Math]::Round($totalmemoryKB / 1024 / 1024)
$limitmemoryMB = $view.SystemResources.Config.MemoryAllocation.Limit
$systemmemoryMB = $totalmemoryMB - $limitmemoryMB
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Stat -Entity hostname -memory`

Comment: This shows statistics for memory usage. It does not give me the number for the system memory. According to the vSphere GUI it's 322.4 MB for the VM host in question.